# Dynamic datasource routing with dynamic datasources

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I found a way to implement dynamic datasource routing described here :

(https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/);

this also can be achieved using hibernate multi-tenancy

(https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html).

My question is, how can datasources be specified, created dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

for wildfly use wildfly-cli
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.wildfly.core%22%20AND%20a%3A%22wildfly-cli%22

```
public static void createDataSource(String server, Integer port, String database, String user, String pass) {
    CommandContext ctx = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder("data-source add");
        cmd.append(" --name=").append(database);
        cmd.append(" --driver-name=postgresql");
        cmd.append(" --jndi-name=").append("java:jboss/datasources/"+database);
        cmd.append(" --connection-url=").append("jdbc:postgresql://"+server+":"+port+"/"+database);
        cmd.append(" --user-name=").append(user);
        cmd.append(" --password=").append(pass);
        cmd.append(" --enabled=true");

        ctx = CommandContextFactory.getInstance().newCommandContext();
        ctx.connectController();
        ctx.handle(cmd.toString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if(ctx != null)
            ctx.terminateSession();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar situation couple of years back . You can refer to the detailed explanation and working [here](https://github.com/soumik-dutta/dynamic_datasource_routing)